# Google Cloud Build not caching custom build steps?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Is it possible to have Google Cloud Build cache custom build step images? It appears to re-download them every build regardless of `latest` vs specific tags used in the name, which makes things slower as opposed to faster.

Comment: Looking over the Cloud Build docs, and based on my own experience/research, I don't think layer caching is supported when using a Dockerfile. Which is unfortunate.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible today. There are [official Cloud Build buildsteps](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders) that are cached, but all custom build steps will be pulled. You can minimize the pull latency by using one of the official buildsteps as a base image of your custom build step.